# Paypal Server Error 403 Forbidden on Wordpress, Plesk

Tags: wordpress, paypal, plesk, shared-hosting

I got problems running PayPal on my WordPress website.

**The symptom is :**

Server Error
403
Forbidden
You do not have permission to access this document.

When going to this folder:

https://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/include/paypal/form-handler2.php

Could you suggest the solution, thank you.

**Key information

1. WordPress
2. PayPal
3. 403 Error
4. Plesk
5. Shared Hosting

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check if file permissions are indeed correct.

Inside the domain directory, folders usually have "755" and documents - "644".
You can check and change it using File Manager in Plesk - **Domains > example.com > /httpdocs**.

Please note that plugins may apply custom permissions on files and folders, so I suggest verifying that there are no such plugins before changing permissions manually.

Additionally, directives defined in web server configuration files located inside the domain directory (`.htaccess` for Apache, `web.config` for Windows IIS) can prevent access to documents, resulting in the same error.